# Best way to find matching id's in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, refactoring

if I have this array of movie ids

```
movies = [28, 14, 100, 53, 37]
```

and this array of objects.

```
genres = [
      {id: 28, name: "Action"},
      {id: 10770, name: "TV Movie"},
      {id: 53, name: "Thriller"},
      {id: 10752, name: "War"},
      {id: 37, name: "Western"}
    ]
```

I would like to return an array of the matching ids. example [ 'Action', 'Thriller', 'Western' ].

I have a solution already but feel that it could be better. What is the best way to refactor this code? Thanks.

```
genre_array = []
movies.forEach(function(e){
  genres.forEach(function(element){
    if (element.id == e) {
     genre_array.push(element.name)
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: I'd always recommend `===` over `==` in Javascript so that it removes any type cohersion. 

Another thing would be to look into immutable methods such as reduce, map and filter. Reason being that it immutability helps to reduce side effects by returning new values rather than mutating and altering existing values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would combine the `filter` and `map` array methods. Use `filter` to get a list of genres that are in your `movies` array, then use `map` to convert that to a list of names.

Example:

```js
const movies = [28, 14, 100, 53, 37]

const genres = [
      {id: 28, name: "Action"},
      {id: 10770, name: "TV Movie"},
      {id: 53, name: "Thriller"},
      {id: 10752, name: "War"},
      {id: 37, name: "Western"}
    ]

// I would like to return an array of the matching ids. example [ 'Action', 'Thriller', 'Western' ].

console.log(genres.filter(g => movies.includes(g.id)).map(g => g.name))
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert `array=movies` to `Set` first (it will improve performances when `array=movies` has a ton of elements), then use `reduce` to pull out all match items.

```js
let movies = [28, 14, 100, 53, 37, 28]

let genres = [
      {id: 28, name: "Action"},
      {id: 10770, name: "TV Movie"},
      {id: 53, name: "Thriller"},
      {id: 10752, name: "War"},
      {id: 37, name: "Western"}
    ]

let indexes = new Set(movies)

console.log(
  genres.reduce((pre, cur) => {
    indexes.has(cur.id) && pre.push(cur.name)
    return pre
  }, [])
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an [array reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to match ids together

```js
const movies = [28, 14, 100, 53, 37]

const genres = [
  {id: 28, name: "Action"},
  {id: 10770, name: "TV Movie"},
  {id: 53, name: "Thriller"},
  {id: 10752, name: "War"},
  {id: 37, name: "Western"}
]

let genre_array = genres.reduce((arr, itm) => movies.includes(itm.id) ? arr.concat(itm.name) : arr, [])

console.log(genre_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```js
const movies = [28, 14, 100, 53, 37]

const genres = [{
    id: 28,
    name: "Action"
  },
  {
    id: 10770,
    name: "TV Movie"
  },
  {
    id: 53,
    name: "Thriller"
  },
  {
    id: 10752,
    name: "War"
  },
  {
    id: 37,
    name: "Western"
  }
]
let genre_array = [];
genres.forEach(function(element) {
  if (movies.includes(element.id)) {
    genre_array.push(element.name)
  }
});
alert(genre_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter and map shorthand

```js
const movies = [28, 14, 100, 53, 37],
genres = [
  {id: 28, name: "Action"},
  {id: 10770, name: "TV Movie"},
  {id: 53, name: "Thriller"},
  {id: 10752, name: "War"},
  {id: 37, name: "Western"}
],
genreList = genres  // filter and a map - shorthand
  .filter(({id}) => movies.includes(id))
  .map(({name})  => name);
console.log(genreList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into a very similar problem this morning and took time out to address one possible oversight, in that the order of the original array is lost with the given solutions.

So I did some digging around and discussion with others (thanks discord!), I've come up with this solution that;

1. Keeps the order of the original array elements (as opposed to the order of the objects).
2. Cleanses null-ish returns and removes any dupes.

```
const movies = [37, 28, "bad data", false ,, 53, 53];
const genres = [
        {
            "id": 28,      
            "name": "Action"
        }, {
            "id": 10770,   
            "name": "TV Movie"
        },{
            "id": 53,      
            "name": "Thriller"
        },{
            "id": 10752,   
            "name": "War"
        }, {
            "id": 37,      
            "name": "Western"
        }];

const genreList  = new Set(
movies
    .map(   element       => genres
    .find(  objectElement => objectElement.id === element)?.name)
    .filter(Boolean));

//Return is [ 'Western', 'Action', 'Thriller' ]
console.log(Array.from(genreList));
```

Importantly, note how the order of the returned array matches the order of the original IDs.

Appreciated the other solutions posted. There are so many ways to achieve so much greatness.  I would love to hear of where my solution could possibly be further improved.